# What is the equivalent of Windows' COM technology in Linux systems?

Tags: linux, windows, matlab, com

I'm using MATLAB on windows to programmatically control another application called CST. I do this via the `actxserver` command which uses COM technology. I'm trying to do the same thing on a Linux cluster but I failed (despite having both MATLAB and CST installed there). I just learned that COM is unique to Windows. Is there an alternative for that on Linux?

Comment: @Daniel I think you misunderstood me. It is just one side, I don't want to do something cross-sides. My local machine is Windows. The cluster is running Linux. I'm doing stuff on my machine, but I cannot do it on the cluster.

Comment: To many things called CST got me confused, reading your question again, I guess you are talking about 3DS CST Studio Suite?

Comment: @Daniel Yes it is! You know it because CST originated from Deutschland LOL.

Comment: As far as I understand, there is no equivalent. Interprocess communication (IPC) evolved very differently on Windows and Linux. COM and ActiveX are an object-based, OS-mediated protocol for communication & control between often-GUI-oriented applications. On, Unix, IPC is done in a more network-y style, using socket-based APIs, web services, and app-specific protocols, because things were built in a client-server manner from the beginning. And on Linux, you generally drive things with `ssh` and command-line tools and communicate with network sockets. So, the answer might be, "nothing really"?

Comment: The closest you're likely to find on the Unix side is CORBA, an object-based IPC protocol. Pretty much nobody talks about CORBA any more, and there's a reason for that.

Comment: Can you give us a link to this CST software? There might be Unix-specific "automation" or API hooks for it that could work for you here. Matlab can plug in to a lot of different protocols these days.

Comment: @AndrewJanke It's a proprietary software with pretty hefty paywall. I think I found a free edition here. https://academy.3ds.com/en/software/cst-studio-suite-student-edition

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Oof da. So, I googled "CST Studio API" and "CST Studio automation" (which is what you should google for in cases like this) and all it came up with is Windows COM stuff. At a first look, it does not look like there is an automation option for CST Studio on Linux. Sad to say, but I think your best bet is to actually call or email the CST Studio people directly and ask what they have for "automation", "scripting", or "APIs" on Linux. And if that doesn't work, look in to what command-line control or file-based batch job options there for it.

Comment: (And if you contact them, maybe don't mention the fact that you're using Matlab; that might distract them. Matlab can interoperate with all the major API and IPC protocols there are these days.)

Comment: @AndrewJanke Thanks Andrews. I will certainly contact them.